# Use IEnumerable.Sum to subtract in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I've been trying to figure out if there was a way to use IEnumerable's Sum method to subtract two values instead of adding them up?

```
IEnumerable<T> list = first
    .Concat(second)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.crita, x.critb})
    .Select(y => new T
    {
        //other fields//
        vara= y.Sum(z => z.vara),
        varb= y.Sum(z => z.varb),
        varc= y.Sum(z => z.varc),
        vard= y.Sum(z => z.vard)
    });
```

I'm using this method to get sums between the two IEnumerables I've joined, but I was hoping to be able to subtract them too.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Also, if someone could tell me how to get products and quotients, that'd be awesome!

Comment: Can you show some example data and output? While we can probably give some direct solution I'm not sure what you are doing is the correct way to approach it

Comment: What would subtracting an `IEnumerable` look like? Subtract all the subsequent ones from the first? Subtract them all from zero? subtract them in pairs and then sum the results? Likewise quotients. They all both binary operators where order or values matters (unlike adding and multiplying where it doesn't matter what order you do it in). Before we can tell you how to do it in LINQ you need to tell us exactly what you want.

Comment: It occurs to me that in what you are doing you might actually have a guarantee that you will only have two items for each combination of criteria in which case the answer to my question is easier but its probably not the best way of doing things (since it won't be at all obvious what you are doing).

Comment: Given two IEnumerables , first and second, I'm trying to generate a third IEnumerable of the same class as the first two. The third IEnumerable just copies the other fields from first, as first and second only have different values once you get to vara, varb, varc, and vard, where it gets the sums of the respective fields from the first and second IEnumerable. 

Getting sums has been the easy bit as I can just use Sum, though now I'm struggling with getting the difference between first.vara and second.vara, for example.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Aggregate` is the elder brother of `Sum` that can do subtract and other aggregations too. On the other hand if you want to do element-by-element subtraction, you can use general `Select` projections.

Reading your comment, one easy trick would be to create a projection of your second `IEnumerable` that negates `vara`, `varb` etc. and then use the same `Sum` function to compute the aggregates of groups. So basically you would just be doing `a + (-b)` instead of `a - b`. Something on the following lines:

```
IEnumerable<T> list = first
                  .Concat(second.Select(n => new T() { vara = -n.vara...} )
                  .GroupBy(x => new { x.crita, x.critb})
                  .Select(y => new T
                  {
                      //other fields//
                      vara= y.Sum(z => z.vara),
                      varb= y.Sum(z => z.varb),
                      varc= y.Sum(z => z.varc),
                      vard= y.Sum(z => z.vard)
                  });
```

Comment: Oh! That's actually rather cool. Thanks!

Would you happen to know where I can read up on Aggregate so I could also implement multiplication and division?

Comment: @Seiche: You can read about Aggregate [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx).